# Find the Hahn distribution of the measure $\nu$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(X, F)$. For given sets $ A, B ∈ F$ we define:
$\nu(H)=\mu(H\cap A) - \mu(H \cap B)$. Find the Hahn distribution of the measure $\nu$.

I don't know if it makes sense, but I started with that: $\nu(H)=\mu(H\cap A) - \mu(H \cap B) = \int_{H \cap A} d\mu - \int_{H \cap B} d\mu $ so it will be $1_{H \cap A} - 1_{H \cap B} \ge 0 $ or $1_{H \cap A} - 1_{H \cap B} \le 0$?

Answer (score 1):

$\nu (H)=\mu (H \cap (A\setminus B)) -\mu (H \cap (B\setminus A)) $ [becasue $\mu (H\cap (A \cap B))$ cancels].

Hence $A\setminus B$ is a positive set and $B\setminus A$ is a negative set for $\nu$.

Comment: We consider sets $ A$ and $B$ as separable?

Comment: The difference sets are disjoint. I don't know what you mean by separable.

Comment: That's what I meant, thanks. I have to prove that $\nu$ is a signed measure. It is obvious for an empty set, but can I write it like this for a countable sum: $\mu (\cup H_{n} \cap A) = \mu(\cup (H_{n} \cap A)= \sum \mu(H_{n} \cap A)$?

Comment: And that $\nu \ll \mu \to \mu(H \cap A) - \mu (H \cap B) = 0 - 0 = 0 = \nu (H)$ because using the definition of absolute continuity we have that: $\mu (A) = 0 \to \nu (A) = 0$. 
Is this solution correct?

Comment: @wvnikax Both of your arguments are correct.